# Displaying numerical attributes as strings in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, domains

I have several columns of research data that are coded 0-2. For example:

```
0=No monkeys in state
1=Some monkeys in state
2=Only monkeys in state
```

When I actually bring this map up to ArcGIS Online, obviously I don't want someone to click on a state and get a popup telling them just an integer. I would like some way of writing a conditional statement that will display whatever string I want instead its numerical code.

Comment: You are describing a coded value domain.  Apparently it has to be set up a particular way to get it to show up in ArcGIS online per this post:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144077/file-geodatabase-coded-domain-not-recogized-by-arcgis-online

Answer (score 0):

Arcmap Options > Tables > uncheck "Display coded value domain and subtype descriptions".

Comment: Please add a little content to your answer.