# Publishing subtypes on ArcGIS Online for Collector?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-collector, subtype

I am kind of new to ArcGIS online and I just publishes a feature hosted map service after I have fixed my data with subtypes and subtypes-domains. After publishing to agol I discovered that all my domains are not working.

I need this for collector and I had intentionally created the domains based on subtypes in order to restrict the data entry based on the subtype.

Comment: See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144077/using-file-geodatabase-coded-domain-with-arcgis-online

Comment: Read this https://community.esri.com/thread/141794

Comment: I would also check to see if this info exists in the service templates. If the data model isnt present in the data model then Collector wont be able to follow the set model and just display the base subtype.